# Summarise comma delimited text file by merging based on column 2 and 3, and calculating the average of column 4

Tags: awk

I have a file that reports every incident of something and its size. I'm trying to summarise that information by merging consecutive incidences which can be identified by column 3 of a line above being the same as column 2 on the line below (so long as column 1 is identical), the output should be in the same format, but rather than multiple lines for any consecutive string, I would have it replaced with a single line where the column 2 would be the lowest number from the grouping in that column, column 3 would be the highest number from the grouping in that column, and column 4 would be the average of all the numbers in column 4 of that grouping (rounded to the nearest whole number).

To be clear, column one is a specific group, column two is a start position, column 3 is an end position, and column 4 is the number of occurrences.

Each line is unique in its combination of columns, the columns are pre-sorted by column 1, then column 2, then column 3. No number in column 2 should/would ever be the same, no number in column 3 should/would ever be the same. Column 1 can, and often will, be the same.

I'm trying to achieve this in awk if possible, I have attempted it already and failed. Here is what I tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","} NR==1 {print} NR>1 {if ($1==prev && $2==end+1) {sum+=$4; count++; end=$3} else {if (NR>2) {print prev, start, end, int(sum/count+0.5);}; prev=$1; start=$2; end=$3; sum=$4; count=1}} END {print prev, start, end, int(sum/count+0.5)}'
```

```
###### reformatted via "awk -o- '...script_body...'"

awk '
BEGIN {
        OFS = ","
}

NR == 1 {
        print
}

NR > 1 {
        if ($1 == prev && $2 == end + 1) {
                sum += $4
                count++
                end = $3
        } else {
                if (NR > 2) {
                        print prev, start, end, int(sum / count + 0.5)
                }
                prev = $1
                start = $2
                end = $3
                sum = $4
                count = 1
        }
}

END {
        print prev, start, end, int(sum / count + 0.5)
}'
```

Example input:

```
fgh1,45513382,45513383,43
fgh1,45513383,45513384,44
fgh1,45513384,45513385,44
fgh1,45513385,45513386,43
fgh1,45513386,45513387,43
fgh1,45513387,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543513,44
fgh2,63543513,63543514,41
fgh2,63543514,63543515,44
fgh2,63543515,63543516,44
```

Example output:

```
fgh1,45513382,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543516,43
```

Comment: (Note that in a codeblock fenced by triple-backticks, the rest of the line after the backticks on the starting fence is used to set the formatting to use. It won't be displayed.)

Comment: I also realised my sample output was wrong, I've corrected it now

Comment: Each line is unique in its combination of columns, the columns are pre-sorted by column 1, then column 2, then column 3. No number in column 2 should/would ever be the same, no number in column 3 should/would ever be the same. Column 1 can, and often will, be the same.

Comment: You say "rounded to the nearest whole number" but what does "nearest" mean for `1.5` - it gets rounded towards `1` because it's lower (round down) or towards `2` because it's higher (round up) or towards `2` because that's even (unbiased rounding) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a couple lines of input where column #1 is the same but there's a gap between the 3rd column and the next line's 2nd column:

```
$ cat raw.dat
fgh1,45513382,45513383,43
fgh1,45513383,45513384,44
fgh1,45513384,45513385,44
fgh1,45513385,45513386,43
fgh1,45513386,45513387,43
fgh1,45513387,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543513,44
fgh2,63543513,63543514,41
fgh2,63543514,63543515,44
fgh2,63543515,63543516,44            # 3rd column (current line) does not match ...
fgh2,63543524,63543525,20            # 2nd column (next line)
fgh2,63543525,63543526,60
```

**NOTE:** it's not clear (to me) from OP's description and sample data if this situation can occur; if it cannot occur then the proposed code should  still work (and the `|| $2 != outcols[3]` could be removed)

General approach:

- keep track of next set of output columns in an array
- when the conditionals do not match then print the array, clear the array, and start populating the array with the next line of output

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

function print_line () {

    if (outcols[1]) {                             # if we have something in outcols[1] then ...
       for (i=1;i<=3;i++)                         # loop through 1st three columns and ...
           printf "%s%s", outcols[i], OFS         # print to stdout then ...
       printf "%.0f\n", (sum / count)             # calculate/print average; let printf/.0f do the rounding
    }

    delete outcols                                # clear array
    sum = count = 0                               # reset counters
}

($1 != outcols[1]) ||
($2 != outcols[3])    { print_line() }

                      { if (! outcols[1]) {       # if nothing in outcols[1] then initialize 1st two output columns ...
                           outcols[1] = $1
                           outcols[2] = $2
                        }
                        outcols[3] = $3
                        sum += $4
                        count++
                      }

END                   { print_line() }            # flush last line to stdout

' raw.dat
```

This generates:

```
fgh1,45513382,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543516,43
fgh2,63543524,63543526,40
```

Comment: Thanks for having a run at this, particularly helpful having the commenting explaining the workings. When I ran this with you input, it worked and I got: fgh1,45513382,45513388,44                                                                                               fgh2,63543512,63543516,43                                                                                               fgh2,63543524,63543526,40                But when I ran it with my input, its gave the completely wrong answer of: chr1,45513382,45513392,43  as an output

Comment: It might be because I'm tired, but your awk command is so far out of my understanding that I can't make head or tails as to why it is working for your input (which is a perfectly good example of possible inputs), and not with my input (which should fit the same logical criteria)

Comment: you mention wrong output starting with `chr1`; is that a typo or did the code really convert `fgh1` to `chr1`? either way, I'm guessing there's something else in your actual data files that could be causing issues; assuming your file is large(ish) ... I'd suggest reducing to just 2-3 lines that demonstrate the faulty output and then run `od -c file_name`, then review the output for anything that's not a generic letter, digit, comma or end of line character (`\n`)

Comment: your faulty output also contains the strings `45513382` and `45513392`, which do not show up in your sample data, so it's hard to say what the problem could be since I don't know what your actual data file looks like; if you run my code against the sample data from the question ... do you get the expected output?

Comment: I apologise, you were right, I used it on the wrong input example. Your method works for both. Since thinking there was no solution yet, I have now solved it and answered it with my own attempt. But I will tick yours as the official answer, as you did get there before me. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I did also up tick your answer, but I guess someone else has down ticked it. Perhaps the same person that down ticked my question

Comment: no problem (re: voting)

Comment: Regarding "let printf/.0f do the rounding" - that may be OK but it does mean you'll get different output on different machines depending on how the underlying C primitives are implemented, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Round-Function.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but my solution would look something like....

```
{
   AGG=$2 "," $3;
   if ( AGG == PREVAGG ) { 
      TOT+=$4;
      COUNT+=1;
   } else {
      if (PREVAGG) {
         print PREVAGG "," int(TOT/COUNT);
      }
      TOT=$4;
      COUNT=1;
      PREVAGG=AGG;
   }
}
END { print PREVAGG "," int(TOT/COUNT); }
```

> I'm trying to sort this in awk if possible

Are you referring to the ordering of records in the input stream? If so, awk is not very good at that. Try `sort -k 1,2,3 -t','`

It looks as if your code is handling a header row in the file but this is not in your expected output. I've ignored that.

**How it works**

`AGG=$2 "," $3` - we output and reset the accumulated data when $2 and $3 change. Treating them as a composite entity saves on some code and complexity. It also makes it trivial to account for additional columns (you didn't specify how values in S1 should be treated).

`if ( AGG == PREVAGG ) {` - are the labels we are aggregating by the same in this input row as the previous one?

- if so, continue to aggregate data
- if not, output the aggregated data, reset the accumulators and the last row labels, but ONLY if this is not the first input record

After the script reaches the last record, there is no change in $2,$3 to trigger output of data - so this is explicitly set in the END block.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have used the word 'sort', I just meant trying to achieve this using awk. Thanks for having a go at this, your code didn't work for me unfortunately, I'm not certain I've fully understood it though, perhaps if you can break down the steps in it I can see if I can think of any edits that might get it working

Comment: Don't use all upper case variable names to avoid clashing with builtin variable names (of which there are more than I could list off the top of my head) and to avoid obfuscating your code by making it look like you're using builtin variables when you [hopefully] aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyone's attempt at this, some were very close, its helped me re-think and put my own answer together.

Here's the solution that seems to work even when I play around with the input:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    OFS = ","
}

{
    if (NR == 1) {
        group = $1
        start = $2
        end = $3
        sum = $4
        count = 1
    } else if ($1 == group && $2 == end) {
        end = $3
        sum += $4
        count++
    } else {
        printf("%s,%d,%d,%d\n", group, start, end, int((sum + count / 2) / count))
        group = $1
        start = $2
        end = $3
        sum = $4
        count = 1
    }
}

END {
    printf("%s,%d,%d,%d\n", group, start, end, int((sum + count / 2) / count))
}'
```

Original question input:

```
fgh1,45513382,45513383,43
fgh1,45513383,45513384,44
fgh1,45513384,45513385,44
fgh1,45513385,45513386,43
fgh1,45513386,45513387,43
fgh1,45513387,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543513,44
fgh2,63543513,63543514,41
fgh2,63543514,63543515,44
fgh2,63543515,63543516,44
```

Original question output:

```
fgh1,45513382,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543516,43
```

Input2:

```
fgh1,45513382,45513383,43
fgh1,45513383,45513384,44
fgh1,45513384,45513385,44
fgh1,45513385,45513386,43
fgh1,45513386,45513387,43
fgh1,45513387,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543513,44
fgh2,63543513,63543514,41
fgh2,63543514,63543515,44
fgh2,63543515,63543516,44
fgh2,63543524,63543525,20
fgh2,63543525,63543526,60
```

Output 2:

```
fgh1,45513382,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543516,43
fgh2,63543524,63543526,40
```

Comment: You should really include that second input/output in your question as it's not obvious how you want non-contiguous rows for the same $1 handled.

Comment: Regarding `(sum + count / 2) / count` from your code above - I don't think that's how you should calculate the "average" because if you had a sum of `10` and count of `100` then that'd produce `(10 + (100 / 2)) / 100` = `0.6` when the real average is `10 / 100` = `0.1`.

Comment: I see the original code in your question included the normal way to round `.5` up - `int(sum / count + 0.5)`, why change it?

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk and only storing the values for one `$1` at a time in memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
($1 != prev[1]) || ($2 != prev[3])  {
    prt()
    beg = $2
    cnt = sum = 0
}
{
    end  = $3
    sum += $4
    cnt ++
    split($0,prev)
}
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( cnt ) {
        print prev[1], beg, end, int( (sum / cnt) + 0.5 )
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk orig_input
fgh1,45513382,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543516,43
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input2
fgh1,45513382,45513388,44
fgh2,63543512,63543516,43
fgh2,63543524,63543526,40
```

The above assumes you want to round `.5`s up.